# Тестирование Spring-test через MockMvc

Tags: java, spring

Добрый день, пытаюсь создать тест для web уровня приложения, есть некий запрос

```
MockHttpServletRequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/URL?params");
this.mockMvc.perform(request).andExpect(ok);
```

Начало теста

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class ControllersTest {
@Autowired
WebApplicationContext wac;

MockMvc mockMvc;

@Before
public void setup() {
    DefaultMockMvcBuilder builder = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac);
    this.mockMvc = builder.build();
}
```

Ну и собственно далее пошел тест.

Но я никак не могу понять, почему он мне возвращает 404 ошибку. То есть ожидается 200, а actual 404.
Как сделать так, чтобы 200 вернул? Может я что-то упустил?

вот стек, но не знаю, даст ли он что-нибудь

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status 
Expected :200
Actual   :404
<Click to see difference>


at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:54)
at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:81)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers$10.match(StatusResultMatchers.java:665)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:171)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Контроллер

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/read/object-attributes")
public class GroupAttributeReadController {

@Autowired
private GroupAttributeService groupAttributeService;
@RequestMapping(value = "/import", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public
@ResponseBody
GroupAttributeBufferListResponse findAll(@RequestParam(value = "pageNum", required = true) int pageNum,
                                         @RequestParam(value = "pageSize", required = true) int pageSize,
                                         @RequestParam(value = "order", required = false) String order,
                                         @RequestParam(value = "orderDir", required = false) String orderDir,
                                         @RequestParam(value = "loadSession") Long loadSession,
                                         @RequestParam( value = "showCorrect", defaultValue = "0") Integer showCorrect,
                                         @RequestParam(value="naviUser") String user,
                                         @RequestParam Map<String, String > params,
                                         HttpServletResponse response, Locale locale) {

}

@RequestMapping(value = "/download", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void download(@RequestParam(value = "loadSession") Long loadSession,
                     @RequestParam(value = "showCorrect", defaultValue = "0") Integer showCorrect,
                     @RequestParam Map<String, String > params,
                     @RequestParam(value="naviUser") String user,
                     HttpServletResponse response, Locale locale) throws IOException {

}

@RequestMapping(value = "/uncommit-session", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public
@ResponseBody
Page<PrmGroupAttributeLoadSession> getAllSession(@RequestParam(value = "fll_id") Long fllId,
                                                 @RequestParam(value = "pageSize") Integer pageSize,
                                                 @RequestParam(value = "pageNum") Integer pageNum,
                                                 @RequestParam(value="naviUser") String user,
                                                 Locale locale) {

}
}
```

Тест

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class ControllersTest {
@Autowired
WebApplicationContext wac;

MockMvc mockMvc;

@Before
public void setup() {
    DefaultMockMvcBuilder builder = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac);
    this.mockMvc = builder.build();
}

@Test
public void testController() throws Exception {
    ResultMatcher ok = MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk();

    MockHttpServletRequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/read/object-attributes/import?pageNum=2&pageSize=5&order=test&orderDir=DESC&loadSession=1&showCorrect=0&naviUser=user&FILTER_Test=Test");
    this.mockMvc.perform(request)
            .andExpect(ok);

    request = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/read/object-attributes/download?loadSession=1&showCorrect=0&&FILTER_Test=Test&naviUser=user");
    this.mockMvc.perform(request)
            .andExpect(ok);

    request = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/read/object-attributes/uncommit-session?fll_id=1&pageSize=5&pageNum=2&naviUser=user");
    this.mockMvc.perform(request)
            .andExpect(ok);

    }
}
```

Comment: покажите весь тест целиком и метод контроллера тоже

Comment: Можно показать текст контроллера, но только удалив выполнение в методах, т.е. показать только входные параметры в методах? Так как это промышленный код

Comment: Вы можете создать [mcve] и добавить его в вопрос

Comment: добавил тест контроллера и теста

Comment: Напишите логер в методы контроллера, может проблема в том что контекст не создает контроллер. Была когда то похожая проблема, решение было - создание конроллера ручками через MockMvcBuilder. Если нужно то поищу и брошу код

Comment: Я вывел через print

Comment: MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = GET
      Request URI = /read/object-attributes/import
       Parameters = {pageNum=[2], pageSize=[5], order=[test], orderDir=[DESC], loadSession=[1], showCorrect=[0], naviUser=[user], FILTER_Test=[Test]}
          Headers = {}

Handler:
             Type = null

Comment: Меня смущает что у меня Handler: Type = null. Такое ощущение, что он вообще не доходит. Дело в том, что я не прописывал никакой конфиг, откуда он знает откуда тянуть какой метод? Точнее я понимаю, он обращается через URL, но вот мне кажется он до сервера не может достучаться.

Comment: ну так для этого я и попросил добавить логер в контроллер если вывода в консоль нет - то значит нету и контроллера(бин не создан)

Comment: логгер есть в контроллере private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GroupAttributeReadController.class); Так как не я владелец продукта, меня просто попросили написать тесты, я написал. но вот не задача, что-то пошло не так( а что, понять не могу(

Comment: Быть может и правда косяк просто в контроллере, что бин не создается.

Answer (score 0):

> Попробуйте альтернативный вариант:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class MvcTest {

private MockMvc mockMvc;

private GroupAttributeReadController groupAttributeReadController = new GroupAttributeReadController ();

@Before
public void setup() {
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(groupAttributeReadController).build();

}

@Test
public void testController() throws Exception {


this.mockMvc.perform(get("/read/object-attributes/import?pageNum=2&pageSize=5&order=test&orderDir=DESC&loadSession=1&showCorrect=0&naviUser=user&FILTER_Test=Test")
            .accept(MediaType.ALL))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
     }
}
```

Comment: Все равно 404 ошибка возвращается :(

Comment: Включил pringt, в Headers запись появилась Parameters = {pageNum=[2], pageSize=[5], order=[test], orderDir=[DESC], loadSession=[1], showCorrect=[0], naviUser=[user], FILTER_Test=[Test]}
          Headers = {Accept=[звездочка/звездочка]}

Comment: `/read/object-attributes/import?pageNum=2&pageSize=5&order=test&orderDir=DESC&loadSession=1&showCorrect=0&naviUser=user&FILTER_Test=Test` а если по этой ссылке перейти в браузере - то точно есть какой то ответ?

Comment: в том то и дело, что нет, то есть нет какого-либо маппинга в проекте. Т.е. если я даже запущу у себя томкат, я все равно не попаду на эту страницу.

Comment: Я хочу понять, нужен ли файл конфига или нет. То есть можно ли без томката протестировать? В проекте кроме pom.xml файла с зависимостями, больше нет никакого конфига

Comment: и данного каталога /read/object-attributes я вообще не вижу в проекте

Comment: 1 Здесь все есть `@Controller
@RequestMapping("/read/object-attributes")
public class GroupAttributeReadController {` 

2 А вы уберите из урла &F‌​ILTER_Test=Test и попробуйте снова

3 Относительно запуска тестов уже напрашивается вопрос - а как вы проверяли до этого. В качестве оттвета:

`@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration`

насколько я помню, этот кусок кода просто запускает mock'и исходя из контекста приложения и у вас есть инстансы контроллеров и сервисов. Доп конфигов не надо.

Comment: Убрал и все равно 404:( Это мой первый тест:)

Comment: Тогда начнем с малого `/` протестите).  Провеьте настройки безопаснности защищены ли целевые странички -- если да то их нужно по другому тестить https://spring.io/blog/2014/05/23/preview-spring-security-test-web-security

Comment: с / тоже 404. На счет безопасности не могу проверить, так как не знаю. Я думаю они сами посмотрят, я передал в такой версии, сказал. что 404 выкидывает. Может косяк в коде все таки

Comment: Безопасность - имеется ввиду что без авторизации страница недоступна и вы можете её проверить как в примерах по ссылке

Comment: возможно и надо, обычно получаем токен. Но я им передал тесты, спасибо за помощь :)

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте в контекст бин

```
    @Bean
GroupAttributeReadController getGroupAttributeReadController (){
reurn new GroupAttributeReadController ();
}
```

также необходимо зависимость GroupAttributeService объявить как @MockBean например, ну и @Configuration аннотацию надо добавить